# CGImageRef consumes lot of memory

Tags: ios, iphone, cgimageref, cifilter, uigraphicscontext

I am creating  blur image for one of my apps screen, for this i am using following code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];


CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage extent]];

blurrImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
  self.blurrImageView.image = blurrImage;
  CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

form the above code i am getting the correct blur image, but the problem is at  `CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage extent]];` at this line.

upto this line memory usage showing is normal, but after this line memory usage is increased abnormally high,

hear is the screenchot of memory usage shown before the execution. memory usage is keep on increasing along the execution of this method , this is before

[image]

and this after execution of the line  `CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage extent]];`

[image]

is this is common behaviour..? i searched answer but i didn't get, so any one faced the same problem please help me on this

one thing i am "not using ARC"

Comment: How big is your image? the memory profiler is run on device or simulator?

Comment: not so much but there is a hike in memory usage after this method execution

Comment: Second UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() is a private API, you're app could be rejected if you want to submit to the AppStore

Comment: as u see in the screen shot, memory usage nearly doubled after execution of this single line of code,

Comment: is there any alternative method to do this ... ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43304/discussion-between-shan-and-andrea)

Comment: Shan pls forgive me UIGetImageFrom etc is not a private API I was confusing with UIGetScreenImge... So sorry shame on me

Comment: ya i checked i am about to post a comment on that, now you only posted ..its oky i got new idea i am completely changing that piece of code with category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experience the same memory consumption problems with Core Image.

If you're looking for alternatives, in iOS 7, you can use `UIImage+ImageEffects` category, which is available as part of the `iOS_UIImageEffects` project at the [WWDC 2013 sample code](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=WWDC%202013) page. It provides a few new methods:

```
- (UIImage *)applyLightEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyExtraLightEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyDarkEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyTintEffectWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor;
- (UIImage *)applyBlurWithRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius tintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:(CGFloat)saturationDeltaFactor maskImage:(UIImage *)maskImage;
```

These don't suffer from the memory consumption issues that you experience with Core Image. (Plus, it's a much faster blurring algorithm.)

This technique is illustrated in WWDC 2013 video [Implementing Engaging UI on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?include=226#226).

Comment: @Shan BTW, I notice that if you use Core Image filters a second time, you don't see further consumption of memory (other than the final image), so clearly this memory usage is not a leak, per se, but rather some internal working cache or something like that. It looks like a cost of doing business with Core Image filters. But `UIImage+ImageEffects` bypasses the problem altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The fact you are using a screenshot could vary the memory usage, on retina display could be more that normal device. The doubled is ok in my opinion because you have the original UIImage and the blur image living in memory, probably also the context will keep some memory. I make a guess:

- You are using a lot of autoreleased object, they will stay in memory
  until the pool is drained, try to wrap the code in an
  autoreleaseblock

```
@autoreleasepool{
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];


CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage extent]];

blurrImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
  self.blurrImageView.image = blurrImage;
  CGImageRelease(cgImage);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice i will change "UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()" and i will find the alternate solution ... thnks ... :)

Comment: No, just throwing in `@autoreleasepool` won't accomplish anything in this situation. That's useful when trying to mitigate high-water mark issues when doing a lot of stuff before yielding back to the run loop, but that's not the issue here. Also, Shan is grabbing non-retina snapshot (because he's not using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`), so I don't think retina v non-retina is an issue here.

Comment: Hi @Rob why not?  We have 2 auto released images: image, and blurrImage, at the end of the pool shouldn't one be released with the pool drain?

Comment: Because as soon as this method finishes, you'll be yielding back to the run loop, at which point the pool is drained for you already, so the explicitly declared pool is redundant. Now, if you had some `for` loop in which you were blurring a whole series of images (e.g. repeatedly blurring one image after another without yielding to the run loop after each), then an explicitly declared pool might be useful. But in this scenario, it's redundant, and represents a conceptual misunderstanding of the problem, namely that even after draining the pool, Core Image is not releasing memory.